# How trouble recalculating divs on media queries

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I've been struggling with this CSS for quite some time now and am looking for some guidance.

My problem is this: I have some tabs that perform in an "elastic" manner, and everything works fine. That is, until I use a media query.

I have a media query at 605px, and when it hits that break point the selector (the blue button) doesn't resize and looks out of place. You can shrink the Coden window to see the effect I"m talking about. Any thoughts on how I can make the tabs change size based upon the size of the Wrapper?

Here's the Codepen link: https://codepen.io/brandonleichty/pen/axNBME

Thank you so much for any input.

```js
var tabs = $('.tabs');
var selector = $('.tabs').find('a').length;
var activeItem = tabs.find('.active');
var activeWidth = activeItem.innerWidth();
$(".selector").css({
  "left": activeItem.position.left + "px",
  "width": activeWidth + "px"
});

$(".tabs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var activeWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
  var itemPos = $(this).position();
  $(".selector").css({
    "left": itemPos.left + "px",
    "width": activeWidth + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.tabs {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.tabs a.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs a i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tabs .selector {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  background: #05abe0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #5ee7df, #43a4ca);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#05abe0', endColorstr='#8200f4', GradientType=1);
}

@media (max-width: 605px) {
  .tabs {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .tabs a {
    padding: 10px 12px;
  }
  .tabs .selector {
    height: 110%;
    top: -5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <div class="selector"></div>
    <a href="#" class="active"></i>Popular</a>
    <a href="#">Upcoming</a>
    <a href="#"></i>My Movies</a>
    <a href="#"></i>Search</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a jQuery function for resizing the window,
but the thing is timeout setting because you use CSS transition with 0.6 sec.
so without setTimeout, it would be looked weird.
I've fully tested below code.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
      var activeWidth = $("a.active").innerWidth();
      var itemPos = $("a.active").position();
      $(".selector").css({
        "left":itemPos.left + "px", 
        "width": activeWidth + "px"
      });
  }, 600)
})
```